# How do I display the filepath field in Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I'm going a bit crazy here -- for some reason I can't figure out how to turn on the file path field in the Finder application in OS X. Here is a picture of what I'm trying to find:

[image: Desired Finder widget]

Note that I'm possibly talking about two things: (1) the application called "Finder", and (2) the file selection window that lots of applications use, which presumably uses Finder under the hood.

How do I turn the file path bar on? I've looked through all the menu options and Googled. Is it called something else in OS X? Does it (dare I say it ...) not exist? (Presumably it does because it's far more essential than all the crap that I had to disable in the toolbar.)

Answer (score 2):

In Finder

`Go`...`Go to Folder`

Shortcut: Command+Shift+G

In Save/Choose Dialogs:

Shortcut: Command+Shift+G
or just type a forward slash

This will open the "go to folder" sheet what almost works like the windows path field.

Two useful links:

[“Go To Folder” is the Most Useful Mac OS X Keyboard Shortcut for Power Users](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/31/go-to-folder-useful-mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcut/)

[Navigation with the Finder Path Bar](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/findertip1.htm)